# How can I `flatmap` streams in Rust?

Tags: stream, rust, rust-actix

I have a [`rusoto_core::ByteStream`](https://docs.rs/rusoto_core/0.36.0/rusoto_core/struct.ByteStream.html) which implements [futures' `Stream` trait](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html):

```
let chunks = vec![b"1234".to_vec(), b"5678".to_vec()];
let stream = ByteStream::new(stream::iter_ok(chunks));
```

I'd like to pass it to [actix_web's `HttpResponseBuilder::streaming`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.7.18/actix_web/dev/struct.HttpResponseBuilder.html#method.streaming) method.

```
use actix_web::dev::HttpResponseBuilder; // 0.7.18
use rusoto_core::ByteStream; // 0.36.0

fn example(stream: ByteStream, builder: HttpResponseBuilder) {
    builder.streaming(stream);
}
```

When I try to do it I receive the following error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<rusoto_core::stream::ByteStream as futures::stream::Stream>::Item == bytes::bytes::Bytes`
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
5 |     builder.streaming(stream);
  |             ^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found struct `bytes::bytes::Bytes`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
             found type `bytes::bytes::Bytes`
```

I believe the reason is that `streaming()` expects a `S: Stream<Item = Bytes, Error>` (i.e., `Item = Bytes`) but my `ByteStream` has `Item = Vec<u8>`. How can I fix it?

I think the solution is to `flatmap` my `ByteStream` somehow but I couldn't find such a method for streams.

Here's an example how `streaming()` can be used:

```
let text = "123";
let (tx, rx_body) = mpsc::unbounded();
let _ = tx.unbounded_send(Bytes::from(text.as_bytes()));

HttpResponse::Ok()
    .streaming(rx_body.map_err(|e| error::ErrorBadRequest("bad request")))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I `flatmap` streams in Rust?

A flat map converts an iterator of iterators into a single iterator (or stream instead of iterator).

#### Futures 0.3

Futures 0.3 doesn't have a direct flat map, but it does have [`StreamExt::flatten`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.flatten), which can be used after a [`StreamExt::map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.map).

```
use futures::{stream, Stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.1

fn into_many(i: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream::iter(0..i)
}

fn nested() -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    let stream_of_number = into_many(5);
    let stream_of_stream_of_number = stream_of_number.map(into_many);
    let flat_stream_of_number = stream_of_stream_of_number.flatten();

    // Returns: 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3
    flat_stream_of_number
}
```

#### Futures 0.1

Futures 0.1 doesn't have a direct flat map, but it does have [`Stream::flatten`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.flatten), which can be used after a [`Stream::map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.map).

```
use futures::{stream, Stream}; // 0.1.25

fn into_many(i: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32, Error = ()> {
    stream::iter_ok(0..i)
}

fn nested() -> impl Stream<Item = i32, Error = ()> {
    let stream_of_number = into_many(5);
    let stream_of_stream_of_number = stream_of_number.map(into_many);
    let flat_stream_of_number = stream_of_stream_of_number.flatten();

    // Returns: 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3
    flat_stream_of_number
}
```

---

However, *this doesn't solve your problem*.

> `streaming()` expects a `S: Stream<Item = Bytes, Error>` (i.e., `Item = Bytes`) but my `ByteStream` has `Item = Vec<u8>`

Yes, this is the problem. Use [`Bytes::from`](https://docs.rs/bytes/0.4.11/bytes/struct.Bytes.html#impl-From%3CVec%3Cu8%3E%3E) via [`Stream::map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.map) to convert your stream `Item` from one type to another:

```
use bytes::Bytes; // 0.4.11
use futures::Stream; // 0.1.25 

fn example(stream: ByteStream, mut builder: HttpResponseBuilder) {
    builder.streaming(stream.map(Bytes::from));
}
```